# Problem with WOL over docking hub when device is shut down from within Linux, but not from within Windows

Tags: wake-on-lan, dock

I have a Dell laptop which is connected to a Dell WD19TB dock. It is set up to be able to dual boot into Windows 10 as well as Kubuntu 22.04 (the problem also existed with 20.04).

When I turn off the laptop from within Windows, then I can send a WOL packet to the MAC address of the NIC of the dock. This does not work when I turn off the laptop from within Kubuntu.

When I connect the network cable directly into the laptop instead of the dock, then I can wake up the laptop after having it shut down from within Kubuntu, when I send the WOL packet to the NIC of the laptop.

What could the issue here?

`ethtool` signals that the NIC is set up correctly, that WOL is active.

```
ethtool enx<mac-address>
Settings for enx<mac-address>:
    Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 32
    Transceiver: internal
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00007fff (32767)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup
                               rx_err tx_err tx_queued intr
                               tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol
    Link detected: yes
```

`lshw -class network` prints

```
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 14
bus info: usb@4:2.4
logical name: enx<mac-address>
serial: <mac-address>
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

The dock is connected via Thunderbolt. Maybe Windows is putting the dock into some sort of standby mode while Kubuntu is powering it off?

Same issue when putting the Laptop to sleep, it won't wake up with a WOL.

Answer (score 0):

Some network interfaces don't have the WOL flag set by default.  You can change this using `ethtool` (can be installed using `apt install ethtool`).

To check if the WOL flag is set, use:

```
ethtool <nic> | grep Wake
```

The output should say something like:

```
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
```

If it says `Wake-on: d` that means Wake-on-LAN is disabled.  `g` is enabled.  You can manually set this flag by typing:

```
ethtool -s <nic> wol g
```

And you can setup for network interfaces to enable this each time the system starts by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto <nic>
iface <nic> ...
        ...
        up ethtool -s <nic> wol g
```

There may be a more modern way of doing this, but I've used this setup for years.  [Debian article with more information](https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan).

Comment: Thanks. This is not the issue, I added more info.